# Is it possible to approve and reject a pushed commit on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

the title speaks clearly.
**If i have a repository in Bitbucket (shared with n people),is it possible to reject or approve a user's "push"?**
*For example, user "x" did "commitX" and pushed it on remote, i would like to check the code and choose from "ok, it works, i approve it and it will be pushed!" and "it doesn't work, keep worning on, i will reject your commit"(the pushed commit will be refused).*
Keep in mind **I would like to keep using bitbucket, i already know other stuff like gerrit code review**

Comment: It's called a pull request. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "pull request' workflow that most services provide.

You have your repo, if someone else wants to contribute the do the following:

- 'fork' your repository into their own repository
- create their own branch and do the work necessary
- submit a pull request on the branch

This way you need to review/approve the commits before they are pulled into your repo

Check out [this link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/) for more information